# Unity both conditions are met in loop causing object moving left to right to "vibrate"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code is here and the output in the terminal.

I dont understand why it "vibrates", moves between a very small figure when the object moves too far to one side. I noticed that sometimes the object would vibrate when moving which was a bug.

Easily recreated when I just move the object to a higher value.

In this case

```
 _leftLimit = -8;
 _rightLimit = 8;
```

Here is the coroutine causing issues. With a log when i move it to the far left. Im excited to see what you make of this. Thanks

```
 public IEnumerator Move(float move) {
    _canMove = true;

    float speed = _speed;

    //if this block move left first move left
   if(_blockInitDir == 0) {
       //make speed positive
       //its a positive speed by default

   } else {
       //make speed negative
       speed = -speed;
   }

    while (_canMove) {

        //moved very far left
        if (this.transform.localPosition.x < _rightLimit
            && this.transform.localPosition.x < _leftLimit) {
            speed = speed * -1;
            Debug.Log(speed + " = speed. X = " + this.transform.localPosition.x);
        } 

        //moved very far right
        if (this.transform.localPosition.x > _leftLimit
            && this.transform.localPosition.x > _rightLimit) {
            speed = speed * -1;
            Debug.Log(speed + " = speed. X = " + this.transform.localPosition.x);

        }

        transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        yield return null;
    }


}
```

This image is in the console when the object is moved to the far left

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its vibrating because as long as the objects transform is past one of the limits, it is constantly doing speed * -1, which is switching the direction it will move in. So what you need to do is instead of just reversing the direction while it is past a limit, you have to make sure it STAYS in that direction. For example, change it to this

```
    if (this.transform.localPosition.x < _rightLimit
        && this.transform.localPosition.x < _leftLimit && speed < 0) {
        speed = speed * -1;
        Debug.Log(speed + " = speed. X = " + this.transform.localPosition.x);
    } 

    //moved very far right
    if (this.transform.localPosition.x > _leftLimit
        && this.transform.localPosition.x > _rightLimit && speed > 0) {
        speed = speed * -1;
        Debug.Log(speed + " = speed. X = " + this.transform.localPosition.x);

    }
```

This makes it so that the direction in which your object is traveling will only change if it is past its limit, and currently moving in the wrong direction.

Comment: So its really just switching the speed back and forth in the same condition not bouncing between the two conditions. Doh, fresh set of eyes. Much appreciated.